# Isn't it necessary to <key, value> types for Hashtable and HashMap in java?

Tags: java

I have seen numerous examples for HashMap as well as Hashtable (in java) where they are declared as:

```
HashMap<KeyType, ValueType> hashmap = new HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>();
```

or

```
Hashtable<KeyType, ValueType> hashtable = new Hashtable<KeyType, ValueType>();
```

However, they are also sometimes declared as:

```
HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
```

or

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
```

Same goes for other collections. I always thought that declaration of the *type* of collection is always a good thing but there are a lot of places where I see them being declared without their types. Can anyone tell which of these methods of declaration is considered *proper*? Or there is no proper way? What is the difference between these two types of declarations?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Adding the types is a help for you because you enable the compiler to check the types at compile time - when you omit the types using *raw* generics, your code may fail at runtime while casting.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Thanks for pointing to the existing question! The answer there is really helpful. I got introduced to a new term *raw types*. I didn't know they were called so. I am not sure though if I should be deleting my question.

Comment: Up to you. If you think it could help anyone, leave it. I do believe it might get deleted automatically in a few days though, if there isn't any activity.

Comment: A lot of Java code was written before generics were introduced to the language, and a lot of people (including myself) feel that generics are more trouble/harm than they're worth.